# Dividing one column vector into different columns, according to the first characters

Tags: r, loops, indexing

I have this kind of column vector, but with 15000 rows:

```
df <- data.frame(c("aaa000_587","aaa000_201","aaa000_577","axx005_449","axx005_497", "bbb101_587", "bbb101_664"))

colnames(df) <- c("0")
```

I would like to identify the first 6 alphanumerical characters, and group them into the same line, like this:

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa000_587 | aaa000_201 | aaa000_577 |
| axx005_449 | axx005_449 |  |
| bbb101_587 | bbb101_664 |  |

The first six characters are what determines the subject's id, so I would like to have every participant's id, regardless of what comes after the underscore, in the same row.
It is expected that each row will contain a different number of columns.

I believe this can work with a for and an if loop. I am blocked and can not get any code to work.
please help!
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `substr` and `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
      mutate(val = substr(`0`, 1, 6), rn = rowid(val)) %>% 
      pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = `0`) %>%
      select(-val)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   `1`        `2`        `3`       
#    <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
#1 aaa000_587 aaa000_201 aaa000_577
#2 axx005_449 axx005_497 <NA>      
#3 bbb101_587 bbb101_664 <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R you could do:

```
reshape(transform(df, time = ave(`0`,id<-substr(`0`, 1, 6), FUN=seq_along), id=id), dir="wide")[-1]

        X0.1       X0.2       X0.3
1 aaa000_587 aaa000_201 aaa000_577
4 axx005_449 axx005_497       <NA>
6 bbb101_587 bbb101_664       <NA>
```

---

This can be broken down into:

```
df$id <- substr(df[,1], 1, 6)
df$time <- ave(df[,1],df$id, FUN=seq_along)
reshape(df, dir='wide')[-1]
         0.1        0.2        0.3
1 aaa000_587 aaa000_201 aaa000_577
4 axx005_449 axx005_497       <NA>
6 bbb101_587 bbb101_664       <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option using `dcast`

```
dcast(
  dt[
    ,
    c("N", "q") := list(seq(.N), substr(`0`, 1, 6)),
    substr(`0`, 1, 6)
  ],
  q ~ N,
  value.var = "0"
)[, -"q"]
```

gives

```
            1          2          3
1: aaa000_587 aaa000_201 aaa000_577
2: axx005_449 axx005_497       <NA>
3: bbb101_587 bbb101_664       <NA>
```

**Data**

```
> dput(dt)
structure(list(`0` = c("aaa000_587", "aaa000_201", "aaa000_577", 
"axx005_449", "axx005_497", "bbb101_587", "bbb101_664")), row.names = c(NA,
-7L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000044a1ef0>)
```